# UIButton Triggering Segue

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, segue

I am trying to link together 2 controllers with segue. I have a view controller with 6 button that after the click on a button will show a `tableviewcontroller`. I made all the link, give the identifier to segue etc.

in the `tableviewcontroller` there is an array that should show filtered results depending on which button trigger the segue

How should I write the `prepareforsegue` method?

This is what i am doing

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "chooseBrand" {

        if sender?.tag == 1 {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! SelectionTableViewController
            let numberOfCameras = destinationController.Camera.count
```

}

the problem is that i receive this error message

> "Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x10a0ef588)
>   to 'myApp.SelectionTableViewController' (0x108658b90)."

How can I define the content of the `tableview` in the `selectiontableviewcontroller` depending on which button is pressed?

Thanks a lot for any kind of help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is the sender here? The error is saying that sender with tag = 1 is not a SelectionTableViewController.

Anyway, what you could do is simply to connect each button to the same action outlet method and the have a generic `segue` between the two controllers. When you then hit button A, B, C, D, E, or F you simply check their `tag`(or store them as variables in your controller class) and send whatever you want to the controller. It's important that the segue you have between the controllers is between two controllers and not a `segue` from each `UIButton` the other controller. In the example below I assume you store each of the six UIButton as class variables.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueFromFirstToSecond" {
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as!   SelectionTableViewController
        if sender = button1 {
            let numberOfCameras = destinationController.Camera.count
        } else if sender == button2 {
            let numberOfCameras = destinationController.Camera.count
        }          
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier(segueProfileToPul, sender: sender)
}
```

Connect all buttons to the `buttonPressed()`. I don't think this line `let numberOfCameras = destinationController.Camera.count`works since the SelectionTableViewController is not instantiated yet and thus has no values in its variables (I think). What you are looking for are probably setting this value so `destinationController.Camera.count = someValue`. Maybe I'm wrong though.

**Edit**
I uploaded a test project showing what I mean. Pay attention to the connections I've made in storyboard. Download [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99198804/SegueTest.zip)

Comment: thanks for the answer. the sender is the button with tag 1. You are right, it doesn't work the destinationController.Camera.count but I found the way to make it work.  I will try to connect the buttons to the @IBAction, but how can I say to the tableviewcontroller to show different values in the table depending on the button clicked?

Comment: What you do is that you could send some sort of flag depending on which button was the sender. You could have a variable in the TableViewController which is set to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 and then setup the layout, data and whatnot depending on this variable. So in prepareForSegue you set the variable: destinationController.variable = 1. Preferably you would use an enum for variable.

Comment: Glad I could help :)!